# How to find the data from 8pm to 6am for one entire week

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time, logic

I want to find the data between 8pm of the previous night and till 6am of the next morning for one entire week.

How do I do this

Code :

```
Select name
     , date 
  from addressnames 
 where extract(hour from date) between (20,21,22,13,0,1,2,3,4,5)
   and date(date) between curdate()-8 and curdate()-1
```

But this doesn't help me in giving previous day's data
This should be done in a

Comment: What does `between (20,21,22,13,0,1,2,3,4,5)` mean? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hi it means the hours should be between 9 pm to 6am

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query